# How do I debug company wide connection issues to a web app?

Tags: laravel, nginx, connection, digital-ocean

We have a web app that many people in the company need to access. Occasionally the web app seems to stop responding to requests.

For example if a resource index page (e.g. orders table view) tries to refresh the resource list it will request the data via an API and display a loading indicator but the request ends up silently failing after a while. This happens to multiple people at the same time but accessing the app during this outage/sluggish period from another network (e.g. mobile data) seems to work. Other websites also don't seem to be affected during this period.

The browser network tab shows the requests as failing after 20-40s but there's no status code. The status text when the request is selected is `failed net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.  It seems like when you don't click the request while it's processing and open up the detail later the timing tab will say it got stuck on the *Stalled* phase. But if you open the request detail while it's being processed it will instead say it got stuck on the *Initial connection* phase. This makes the timing tab of the request detail seem unreliable as what it shows seems to depend on whether I was inspecting the request at the time it was being processed or not.

The server doesn't seem to show major overload during this time - max 30% CPU/memory usage.
The server is running on a Digital Ocean droplet and using nginx to host the Laravel app.
The app itself does have throttling enabled but it's bound to the user ID, returns a *Too many attempts* error message and a defined status code so if this is a case of throttling it should not be at the app level.

What can I do to debug / investigate where the issue is coming from? From what I understand the issue can be anywhere from nginx configuration to ISP provider throttling. I am thinking this is some kind of throttling at the moment but could I be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Might be the RateLimiter kicking in which is configured for all api routes in laravel by default.

Have a look at

```
app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
```

```php
    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting(): void
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: That would be an option but as I said in the post I've already considered this and because Laravel's rate limiting returns the 429 error code and an error message which we can trigger outside of this other outage/throttling behavior outlined I don't think it's the Laravel rate limiter causing problems.